# Tabs default action is not stopped event though i use e.preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am showing a text area in a modal when I pressed tab it moves to the next input I wrote code to stop this but I didn't work for me.(when I pressed tab the execution even not coming to the acceptTabsSpace function)

```
$(document).on("keyup", "#collection-text-input", acceptTabsSpace);
function acceptTabsSpace(e){
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (keyCode == 9) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the listener to trigger on `keydown` instead:

```
$(document).on("keydown", "#collection-text-input", acceptTabsSpace);
function acceptTabsSpace(e){
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if (keyCode === 9) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use keydown instead key up and for tabspaces press tab twice.

```
$(document).on("keydown", "#collection-text-input", acceptTabsSpace);
  function acceptTabsSpace(e) {
   var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
   if (e.keyCode === 9) {
     e.preventDefault();
     this.value = this.value.substring(0, this.selectionStart) + "\t" + 
     this.value.substring(this.selectionEnd);
     this.selectionEnd = s + 1;
   }
}
```